# Auth0 with React and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, auth0

I am currently trying to implement a react app with Auth0 for authentication, and i am new to typescript.

Have tried the code below in my  `Auth.js` and it works fine but when i tried to migrate my `Auth.js` file to `Auth.ts` i get the red squiggly  with the errors

> Property 'history' does not exist on type Auth
>
> Property 'userProfile' does not exist on type Auth e.t.c

```
        import auth0 from "auth0-js";
    const REDIRECT_ON_LOGIN = "redirect_on_login";
   export default class Auth {
     constructor(history) {
      this.history = history;
      this.userProfile = null;
      this.requestedScopes = "openid profile email";
      this.auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
      domain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN,
      clientID: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
      redirectUri: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL,
      audience: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
      responseType: "token id_token",
      scope: this.requestedScopes
     });
    }

  login = () => {
    localStorage.setItem(
      REDIRECT_ON_LOGIN,
      JSON.stringify(this.history.location)
    );
    this.auth0.authorize();
  };

  handleAuthentication = () => {
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        this.setSession(authResult);
        const redirectLocation =
          localStorage.getItem(REDIRECT_ON_LOGIN) === "undefined"
            ? "/"
            : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(REDIRECT_ON_LOGIN));
        this.history.push(redirectLocation);
      } else if (err) {
        this.history.push("/");
        alert(`Error: ${err.error}. Check the console for details`);
        console.log(err);
      }
      localStorage.removeItem(REDIRECT_ON_LOGIN);
    });
  };
```

[image]

I want to be able to implement auth0 authentication with react & typescript

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Auth0 types:

```
npm i @types/auth0
```

or this one:

```
npm i @types/auth0-js
```

and if these solutions doesn't work exclude the `Auth0` package in your `tsconfig.js` file like this:

```
"exclude": [
        "node_modules/auth0-js"
    ]
```

just find the Auth0 directiory and exclude it.

Comment: have installed `@types/auth0-js` and `@types/auth0-lock`...still having the same issues

Comment: I've just edited my answer. exclude the package from typescript path.

Answer (score 0):

in typescript "class" is also a type. So when you are using "class", you are creating two things.

1- javascript class function

2- typescript type

Since class is treated as type too, you have to specify the types of properties and methods.

```
class Auth{
  history:findTheTypeOfHistory;
  userProfile:typeofUserProfile
  .
  .
 }
```